# Как вставить javascript в printf()

Tags: php, html

Нужно вставить JavaScript в функцию printf()

```
printf("<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
            })          
        </script>");
```

Проблема возникает в 3 строке с tooltip. Он подсвечивается и собственно не работает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кто такой `printf` ? и откуда он в js взялся?

Comment: Вы так и не ответите?

Comment: Смотрите, у вас там неэкранированные кавычки вокруг tooltip, и фактически они составляют две пары с кавычками внутри скобок. Даже по подсветке синтаксиса это заметно.

Comment: Проблема со вставкой функции решена? Теперь можно создавать новый вопрос, в котором уже показывать, что у вас за элемент на странице, что вы хотите с ним сделать и какой код вы для этого используете, помимо указанной функции.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Экранируйте кавычки:

```
printf("<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]').tooltip()
            })          
        </script>");
```

Подробнее - в справочнике по PHP: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Например, если вы используете одинарные кавычки и внутри них вам нужен символ одинарной кавычки, то:

> Чтобы использовать одинарную кавычку внутри строки, проэкранируйте ее
>   обратным слешем (`\`)

То же самое и с двойными кавычками, как у вас.

Comment: Уже пробовал - не работает. Проблема значит в другом

Comment: Если вы скопируете мой код, то вам хотя бы подсветка синтаксиса покажет, что теперь код у вас верен синтаксически. А "не работать" может по множеству причин. Например, у вас не будет такого элемента на странице. Ошибок у вас может быть несколько, но эту вам исправить обязательно, иначе до остальных даже и не дойдёт дело. А какие другие ошибки -- из вашего кода непонятно, потому что приведено слишком мало кода. Возможно, стоит в отдельном вопросе разбираться с другими ошибками.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]').tooltip();
           });        
        </script>");
```